# How to validate output values of LWC in Lightning Flow

Tags: lightning, lightning-web-components, visual-workflow, screen-flow

I am working on Lightning Flow Screen. I have a new requirement in which I have to validate output value returned from Lightning Web Component (LWC) present on the screen flow. Along with this, a error message should be displayed on the Screen when the conditions are not met.

For standard input element validation option is present in Screen Flow but is there any way using which I can add validations on such custom components used?

Any help or idea related to this would be a great help.

Thanks.

Comment: welcome to SFSE! Please take a moment to visit the [help], scroll through the [tour], and read [ask]. What is the LWC doing exactly? ex. Multiple input fields, just one, etc.

Answer (score 1):

If you have the ability to modify the code of the custom component, you can [add validation logic that gets called when the user tries to leave](https://unofficialsf.com/validation-in-flows-overview/). If you don't have that ability, then you'd have to add an additional screen and carry out validation after the user clicks Next.